# how to synchronize 2 components(traffic light) that show 2 different colors based on dynamic on/off times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components that represent a traffic light that shows red and green colors and they are synchronized with each other. The time for each color of the traffic light will be dynamic, based on the traffic data we get but they are synchronized (if one traffic light has a green color for 8 seconds, the other one must have red for 2 seconds (assuming the total would be 10 seconds).

The code below works, but what if every 10 seconds(i will call an API) I want to change their green/red times. How would you approach it?

```
 const [bottomToUp, setBottomToUp] = useState({
    redLight: false,
    greenLight: true,
    greenOnTime: 6,
    redOnTime: 4,
  });

  const [rightToLeft, setRightToLeft] = useState({
    redLight: true,
    greenLight: false,
    greenOnTime: 4,
    redOnTime: 6,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        setBottomToUp((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          redLight: !prevState.redLight,
          greenLight: !prevState.greenLight,
        }));
      },
      bottomToUp.redLight
        ? bottomToUp.greenOnTime * 1000
        : bottomToUp.redOnTime * 1000
    );
  }, [bottomToUp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        setRightToLeft((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          redLight: !prevState.redLight,
          greenLight: !prevState.greenLight,
        }));
      },
      rightToLeft.redLight
        ? rightToLeft.greenOnTime * 1000
        : rightToLeft.redOnTime * 1000
    );
  }, [rightToLeft]);


       return (<div>
          <TrafficLight
            RedOn={rightToLeft.redLight}
            GreenOn={rightToLeft.greenLight}
          />
          <TrafficLight
            RedOn={bottomToUp.redLight}
            GreenOn={bottomToUp.greenLight}
          />
      </div>)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the traffic lights are dependent on each other, that should be reflected in the code. The synchronisation could be done a bit more effectively without separating the state of the traffic lights. Aside from keeping a single state, if you want to keep red and green lights in sync you should keep one fixed and calculate the other from the total length and the fixed light length.

```js
const [bottomToUp, setBottomToUp] = useState({
  greenLight: true,
  greenOnTime: 1,
  totalSemaphoreTime: 3,
})
/** Using ref here because the state changes would cause the useEffect hook to reevaluate and clear the previous timeout before it was completed */
const bottomToUpRef = useRef(bottomToUp)
bottomToUpRef.current = bottomToUp

const fetchNewGreenOnTimeFromAPI = () => {
  const newGreenOnTime = getFromAPI()
  setBottomToUp(prev => ({ ...prev, greenOnTime: newGreenOnTime }))
}

useEffect(() => {
  let timeoutId

  const timeout = () => {
    return setTimeout(
      () => {
        setBottomToUp(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          greenLight: !prevState.greenLight,
          timerStarted: false,
        }))
        timeoutId = timeout()
      },
      bottomToUpRef.current.greenLight
        ? bottomToUpRef.current.greenOnTime * 1000
        : (bottomToUpRef.current.totalSemaphoreTime -
            bottomToUpRef.current.greenOnTime) *
            1000 /** Only using the greenLight as parameter since red light is dependent on green light */,
    )
  }

  timeoutId = timeout()

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(
      timeoutId,
    ) /** You should always clear timeout when component unmounts */
  }
}, [])

return (
  <div>
    {/** Switched the right to left semaphore values to be reflected from the bottomToUp state since they are dependent */}
    <TrafficLight
      RedOn={bottomToUp.greenLight}
      GreenOn={!bottomToUp.greenLight}
    />
    <TrafficLight
      RedOn={!bottomToUp.greenLight}
      GreenOn={bottomToUp.greenLight}
    />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  in my case, the total amount is the same. the variable that needs to change is bottomUp.greenLight (which I will calculate based on traffic data from the backend). How can I change the bottomUp.greenLight every 10 seconds( but i have to wait for the current cycle to finish) ? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I've updated the solution. In this solution you can fetch new `greenOnTime` from the API and it will not cause the current timeout to change. Only the next one will use the new `greenOnTime` value. The ref is necessary because we do not want to reevaluate the `useEffect` when the `bottomToUp` changes because it would cause the previous timeout to call the clean up function and it would stop the previous timeout to finish @BesartMarku